# Check nsdate is within other 2 nsdate but ignore year

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have written code like this to check whether my date is within other 2 date.

```
+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate {
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    return YES; 
}
```

Problem is that I need to ignore year. It need to be true for 2017, 2018, etc. How shall I re-write?

Comment: You could use NSDateComponents to "get rid of the year".

Comment: Hi sorry. Can you explain with some code?

Comment: In your code there is an assumption right? Like `beginDate` & `endDate` are in the same year, no? If not, you need to add +1 year to the `endDate` if it's earlier than `beginDate` after you set it to the same year as `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Change year of beginDate and endDate to date year by using below code:-

```
+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate {
    NSUInteger componentFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth;
     NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:componentFlags fromDate:date];
    NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];


    NSDateComponents *beginDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:componentFlags fromDate:beginDate];
    [beginDateComponents setYear:year];
    beginDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:beginDateComponents];


    NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:componentFlags fromDate:endDate];
    [endDateComponents setYear:year];
    endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];

    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```